# How to compare two lists and determine if they have common string elements?

Tags: python, comparison, string-comparison

I have lists of domains:

```
domains_1 = ['google.com', 'payments-amazon.com']
domains_2 = ['https://static-eu.payments-amazon.com/OffAmazonPayments/de/lpa/js/Widgets.js']
```

In this case, `payments-amazon.com` is the common domain. How would I go about finding this, given that domain names can be long and unique?

I have tried this, but this only works if the domains are exact. I need them to match if they include part of the domain in the list/string:

```
matches = (set(domains_1).intersection(domains_2))
print(matches)
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
Repeat your string tutorials; look for the sections on substring checking.  If you get stuck, search for substrings in a list of strings.

Comment: Seems like a nested loop is unavoidable: `for short in domains_1: for long in domins_2: if short in long: print(long)`

Comment: You will need to extract the domain from each list element so you can compare them to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a package like tldextract - which works great except in a AWS lambda setup.  Or you can use something like this to get the domain from your URL.

```
def extract_domain(url):
    from urllib.parse import urlparse
    parsed_domain = urlparse(url)
    domain = parsed_domain.netloc or parsed_domain.path # Just in case, for urls without scheme
    domain_parts = domain.split('.')
    if len(domain_parts) > 2:
        return '.'.join(domain_parts[-(2 if domain_parts[-1] in {
            'com', 'net', 'org', 'io', 'ly', 'me', 'sh', 'fm', 'us'} else 3):])
    return domain

for x in domains_2:
    dom = extract_domain(x)
    if dom in domains_1:
        do your thing
```